# Getting More Health

Tags: candy-box-2

I'm playing Candy Box Two, and have noticed in some questions that people have an increased health bar.  I am stuck on the forest level, and can't seem to kill the enemies in the cave. How do I increase my health?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get more health, you need to eat candies.